# Getting the AR(p) values from ARMA model in R

Tags: r, arima, forecast

I am interested to get the values of the AR(p) part from any ARIMA model in R.

For example, suppose I estimate the following ARIMA model

[image]

I am interested to get these values defined as:

[image]

What I do is this:

```
  ar_model <- auto.arima(mydata) # fit an ARIMA model as decided by the auto.arima
  fitted_ar_model <- fitted(ar_model)
  resid_ar_model <- residuals(ar_model)
  ar_p <- fitted_ar_model - resid_ar_model
```

The thing with code is that I am not sure whether the `residuals(ar_model)` include only the contemporaneous residuals or also the moving average part.

Comment: It is not clear whether the `auto.arima` actually fits a pure AR, MA or ARMA model - you need to inspect the parameters. In any case, `residuals` will **not** include the MA part (if present) as the MA part is part of the fit. The last line seems weird to me since the fitted values are already actuals - residuals, so what would be the reason for subtracting the residuals again?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Ok then, what needs to be done to get what I want using the example I provided ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt an answer here. Unfortunately, writing formulas in SO is really cumbersome. So, firstly, I think you need to make a distinction between the "epsilon" of your DGP (data generation process), also called shocks or errors (which are unobservable) and the model **residuals**. Shocks are unobservable because you don't know the **true** values of the model parameters (in this case the AR and MA parameters) - you can only **estimate** them. So there is a difference (in a simple AR(1) model without a constant for ease of writing using a "hat" notation for estimates) between y_t - phi_1*y_{t-1} and y_t - \hat{phi_1}*y_{t-1} - the former being the "shock" and the latter being the "residual". Typically you would also have as notation \hat{y_t}  = \hat{phi_1}*y_{t-1} and so residual defined as e_t = y_t - \hat{y_t}.

Now so, given that, I think what you would like to get is y_t - e_t - \hat{phi}*e_{t-1}, \hat{phi} being the estimated MA1 parameter. The following is an example where I have explicitly fitted an ARMA(2,1) without a constant to the `LakeHuron` time series. I have looked at the model residuals using `residuals` (`resid` in `df`) and also calculated by hand (`resid2` in `df`) - they differ a bit due to approximating initial conditions that the `residuals` method makes which I didn't really dig into. You will see that the values get closer and closer as `t` increases and the influence of the initial conditions diminishes (this is due to the fact that we have a stationary ARMA model). In the same way I have calculated the "AR_fit" as I call it once as ar_1 * y_{t-1} + ar_2 * y_{t-2} (`ar_fit1` in `df`) and a second time as y_t - e_t - ma_1 * e_{t-1} (`ar_fit2` in `df`). Again, you will see that the values converge as `t` increases (due to the same initial conditions used to calculate the residuals using the `residuals` function).

```r
library(forecast)
data <-  LakeHuron - mean(LakeHuron)

nobs <- length(data)

ar_model <- arima(data, order = c(2, 0, 1), include.mean = FALSE)
fitted <-  fitted(ar_model)
resid <- residuals(ar_model)

ar1 <- ar_model$coef[1]
ar2 <- ar_model$coef[2]
ma1 <- ar_model$coef[3]

df <- data.frame(data, fitted, resid)

resid2 = data[3:nobs] - ar1*data[2:(nobs-1)] - ar2*data[1:(nobs-2)] - ma1*resid[2:(nobs-1)]
resid2 <- c(NA, NA, resid2)
df$resid2 <- resid2

ar_fit1 <- ar1*data[2:(nobs-1)] + ar2*data[1:(nobs-2)]
ar_fit1<- c(NA, NA, ar_fit1)
df$ar_fit1 <- ar_fit1   

ar_fit2 <- data[3:nobs] - resid[3:nobs] - ma1*resid[2:(nobs-1)]
ar_fit2<- c(NA, NA, ar_fit2)
df$ar_fit2 <- ar_fit2
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this explanation